# When exported to csv it changes some cell names, how can i prevent this?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some data points (gene id) that are like "dates" for example MAR1 but when i export it to csv it keeps changing it to 1.Mar as if it's an actual date.
How can I keep it as MAR1 not keep changing it as date format?
When i try to fix this on excel it trying to change it into txt format it changes into cell number.

Comment: Check the class(dates) before exporting. If is in Date format you probably can solve this changing to character

Comment: Is it being changed in the csv, or by Excel when you use Excel to open the csv?  If you want to open it in excel, then why not use `writexl` package to save it in the first place.  This way you can force character format and not date format

Comment: What program are you exporting from? This sounds like a classic problem that occurs in Excel, not R.

Comment: Im exporting from R, the file format of the data is in txt.gz format. The data publisher put it in that format which requires R, I don't think python can read that file format

Comment: @EmilyNwo Judging from the file ending, this is just a zipped text file. You don't need R to open such a file. You just need to unzip and then can use any text editor. You should definitely be able to open that file in python.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into PowerQuery if you are working with CSV format.

Open a blank workbook, instead of opening the file go to the Data Tab -> Get Data -> From Text/CSV and locate the file.

(You can also pick Excel file if you plan to use writexl)

Click "Transform Data" and from there you can pick which formats you want by clicking on the small icons in the columns (in your case set the column to text). You can also do many other things such as sort or convert a data to a week number.

Click "Close & Load" and it will appear in a new tab as a table.

What's nice about PowerQuery if you are doing any post analysis in Excel is that next time you export in R, you only have to hit "Refresh All" in the data tab and it will pull your new data in and apply transformations provided you haven't changed any of the column/names.

[image: Power Query Editor]